# How to fix : R Error: replacement has length zero

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I wanted to find out MWTP(marginal willingness to pay) from the coefficient i found from my model. [Coefficients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twQov.jpg)
But i am facing one problem that the R is showing I have an error like

```
"Error in nonmonetary.index[i] <- which(names(est.coef) == unlist.nonmonetary.variables[i]) :    replacement has length zero"
```

How can i fix it please help me out.[MWTP error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEPDe.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It was just a mistake of capital letter by me. I have used small letter in my code where as i have used capital letter previously. It looked like same so i didn't find that. Now i have the answer.
[MWTP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s777j.jpg)